# Class Initializer checking for certain input

Tags: c++, class, c++11, variables, initialization

I have a Class in a header file and I am trying to implement the initializing given a certain input. 
So my header file excluding headers looks something like this:

```
class Card {
public:
  // rank and suit names
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_TWO = "Two";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_THREE = "Three";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_FOUR = "Four";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_FIVE = "Five";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_SIX = "Six";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_SEVEN = "Seven";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_EIGHT = "Eight";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_NINE = "Nine";
  static constexpr const char* const RANK_TEN = "Ten";

  static constexpr const char* const SUIT_SPADES = "Spades";
  static constexpr const char* const SUIT_HEARTS = "Hearts";
  static constexpr const char* const SUIT_CLUBS = "Clubs";
  static constexpr const char* const SUIT_DIAMONDS = "Diamonds";

Card();

Card(const std::string &rank_in, const std::string &suit_in);

private:
  std::string rank;
  std::string suit;
};
```

For the implementation of the second initializer I have this so far.

```
Card::Card(const std::string &rank_in, const std::string &suit_in){

    this->rank = rank_in;
    this->suit = suit_in;
}
```

To check if my rank_in and suit_in match one of the variables inside the class, do I need to check each one individually or is there a way to do this more efficiently? Thanks in advance the help is much appreciated

Comment: by initializer you mean constructor right??

Comment: As a side note, any reason why you are using C-style strings instead of std::string for the rank and suit names?

Comment: @Caw: why would you use a `std::string` when you know the string at compile-time and can mark it `constexpr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> or is there a way to do this more efficiently?

yes, you can explode the new c++11 features:

```
class K 
{
    public:
        enum class R
        {
            TWO,
            THREE,
            FOUR
        };
        enum class Su
        {
            S,
            H,
            C,
            D
        };
        K(const R someR, const Su someSu);
    private:
        R r;
        Su su;
};
#endif /* K_H */

K::K(const R someR, const Su someSu): r{someR}, su{someSu}
{

}
```

with this approach you are avoiding the user of the class to make mistakes by mixing the types of your parameters in the constructor...

Comment: Please don't explode the C++11 features, we still need them! :(

Comment: On a more serious note: Please choose real words for your type and variable names instead of one letter abbreviations. There is simply no reason to write `Su` instead of `Suite`, `K` instead of `Card` etc.

Comment: @MaxLanghof hi max, thanks for the comment... you know, I was trying to post as fast as i can... for sure we need to use more descriptive names for all the classes and its members... :)

Answer (score 1):

Just offhand, I would make two more classes, one called Rank and the other Suit.  They each should have constructor that takes a string and a function isValid().  Then you can initialize rank and suit in the Card class and then check whether they are valid before proceeding with anything.  Sort of like this:

```
class Rank {
   public:
      Rank(std::string s) : mRank(s) { }
      bool isValid() const { /* check against all valid strings */ return true; }
   private:
      std::string mRank;
}
```

Maybe initialize a string array in the class with the valid strings and loop through the elements to test, or a simple brute force check like above.

Comment: Seems like a very roundabout way of solving the problem, using an enum would be far more simple.

Comment: I'm just guessing he wants to keep being able to use strings in the constructor.